# How to stack a series of 2D arrays within a for loop, outputting to a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a function which I would like to run (in *python 3.7*) at a series of sensor heights (z). Each resulting *2D array* should be stacked into a single multi-dimensional array which I can then access later. I have not been able to combine my outputs, and right now each time I run my for-loops it just overwrites the previous run.

I've tried using np. stack and concatenate and have tried using np.append outside of the stack, as well as trying things like `np.stack(AS_temp[k])`, which resulted in an error.

```
AS = np.zeros((len(z),len(x),len(y)))  
for k in range(len(z)):
    AS_temp = np.sqrt((GradX[k]**2) + (GradY[k]**2) + (GradZ[k]**2))
    AS = np.stack(AS_temp,axis = 0)
```

The for loop should go through each z value, calculate the AS_temp function (which is a 2D array), and then add it vertically to my multi-dimensional array AS. In the end I would like a 3D space where each horizontal '`slice`' represents a z value from the for loop.

Comment: First off, what is the error? What is the shape of GradX, GradY, and GradZ? What is the desired output shape?

Comment: I formatted your code, but I'm not sure if it retains the meaning that you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to accomplish this. If you still want the numpy.zeros

```
AS = np.zeros((len(z),len(x),len(y)))  
for k in range(len(z)):
    AS[k] = np.sqrt((GradX[k]**2) + (GradY[k]**2) + (GradZ[k]**2))
```

No stacking. If you want to use stack, you need to use it at the end. (As per the documentation that says, "Each array must have the same shape."

```
AS_stack = []
for k in range(len(z)):
    AS_stack.append(np.sqrt((GradX[k]**2) + (GradY[k]**2) + (GradZ[k]**2)))
AS = np.stack(AS_stack,axis = 0)
```

Or, if GradX,GradY, and GradZ are actually arrays also:

```
AS = np.sqrt((GradX**2) + (GradY**2) + (GradZ**2))
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed! :)

Comment: @Canada cool, you can accept it with the check mark by the upvote/downvote button. Also, which method did you end up using?

Comment: Thanks- done! I used your first answer, starting with a zeros matrix.